# polaris sep-31 send stuck at pending_sender state in kubernetes

Tags: anchor

I have tried to test sep-31 sending using polaris (v1.0.2) in kubernetes cluster.

When I used demo-wallet and sep-31 send, transaction.asset.distribution_account is not defined and got an error in process_post_response function of sep31/transaction.py file.

when I used hard-coded transaction.asset.distribution_account value, transaction was created and send in stellar network worked.

But status in transaction did not change from pending_sender to pending_receiver and stacked this pending_sender. When analyzed network in browser's developer tool, in transaction object, stellar_account_id and stellar_transaction_id are still null.

How can I proceed to pending_receiver state and finish sep-31 send?